# She watches movies ...... at the theatre ..... every Sunday?

Tags: prepositions, british-english

> She watches movies ......  the theatre ..... every Sunday?

Ans:

> She watches movies ***at*** the theatre every Sunday.

My approach: I write this sentence as:

> She watches movies ***at*** the theatre ***on*** every Sunday.

I made this because "at" is used to denote a person here for the short period of time, and "on" is used to denote days. It's a rule that we can use in the above example and also in these words like *on/in* the next November, *on/in* the next month, *in/on* the last month.

> My question is: If the words "last", "next" and "every" are of the same type,Why they are not used with prepositions and Are there any other words I need to know about?

I found some similar sentences where no preposition was used like:

- > She went home this evening.
- > She went upstairs
- > She went downstairs
- > She went inside
- > She went outside
- > She went downside
- > She went upside
- > She went cycling

Comment: I'm still struggling to find a 'question' here!

Comment: If you want to fill the blank: *"She watches movies in the theater every Sunday."* You don't need anything before 'every Sunday'.

Comment: @MaulikV edited please see.

Comment: @MaulikV Why I don't need anything before 'every Sunday'?

Comment: @justintakro - that's just how the language works.  The words "day", "week", "month", "year", etc. (up and down the scale) when combined with "every" designate the frequency of something occurring and no preposition is needed.  "Every year we celebrate our birthdays together".

Comment: I don't know who told you that *'"at" is used to denote a person here for the short period of time'*, because that is wrong. Examples: *I was at the theater forever*. *I lived at the corner of Main Street and Broadway for 62 years.* @justin

Comment: At the theatre?

Answer (score -1):

**No**! Read [this](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/prepositions-of-time.html).

> We don't use a preposition with these words:

- **next** week, year, month etc
- **last** night, year etc
- **this** morning, month etc
- **every** day, night, years etc

and with words **today**, **tomorrow**, **yesterday**!

---

Consider the usage of **"in"** vs **"at"** with the word **"theater"**:
[image]

**In the theater** here refers to the building *(the theater itself)*. In British English, **At the theater** means *attending a performance*. However, both prepositional forms, **at** and **in** are regularly found, but **in** is more common with the generic term theater and **at** with a specific theater name.